# pgfplots - Manual file (.pdf) asks me if I want to save the changes

Tags: pgfplots

Why does the manual for `pgfplots` have that prompt? I use it like every other file: I search for things, copy them, close it. That's it. The prompt is only for this very file.

Comment: I don't know the exact reasons, but I think it is related to the interactive features of the plots in the manual. I am not sure what exactly it will save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@alfC's comment is correct: it is the "clickable" lib which results in this annoying and misleading message. There is nothing to save.

The purpose of the clickable lib is to allow clicking into plots and access meta data for individual points (if available).

Comment: Ah, I see. I think I may have stumbled upon them a very long time ago but I can't recall for sure. So, is it possible to maybe receive a non-interactive version of the manual? Or to turn the prompt off? It surely must have come up on your end, right? :)

Comment: I have never created a non-interactive version. I could create one. Maybe something like pdf2pdf will also result in a non-interactive version. The best would be to suppress the popup altogether, but I fear there is no suitable switch :-(

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you could be a (experimental) non-interactive version. :) I think so too, AFAIK there is no switch option to turn off the prompt.